# How to skip login page with Argo Workflows SSO

Tags: single-sign-on, openid-connect, argo-workflows, argo

I have an Argo Workflows instance with SSO configured. When I click a workflow link it takes me to the login page if I'm not signed in, which forces me to click the LOGIN button to redirect me to my SSO provider, which then redirects me to the workflow when successful.

Does anyone know if it's possible to configure SSO auth so that the login page is skipped and users are redirected directly the the SSO sign in page? I've been looking through documentation and source code with no luck and thought I'd ask here before giving up.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been open for a long time and causing me to loose reputation. I still think this is a perfectly valid question that must be answered, but I do not want to loose reputation over a question that no one can answer. I wish I knew why this and another question are loosing reputation.

Comment: Same here and agree this is a valid question. Cool if anyone can find better option than suggested my workaround below

Comment: It doesn't seem like there's a proper way of doing this today. [Issue #8179](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/issues/8179) has been open for several years and includes SSO as a use-case.

Answer (score 0):

We end-up using workaround.
Initially we tried to use same url as for Argo CD: `https://argo-cd.example.com/auth/login`
so we set this: `https://argo-workflows.example.com/auth/login`, but this not works.

We tried several others:

1. https://argo-workflows.example.com/oauth2/login
2. https://argo-workflows.example.com/login
3. https://argo-workflows.example.com/oauth2/redirect?redirect=https://argo-workflows.example.com/workflows

Number 3 works, but sometimes throw 401.